# sed command to print a string after certain pattern

Tags: regex, sed

Trying to print a string using sed after a line/statement as below,

```
class name extends #(p val1 = 10,
                     p val2 = 20,
                     p val3 = 30) f_name;
```

"**class**" and "**extends**" and "**;**" at the end of that line/statement (ie, consuming multiple lines) will remain constant, rest of the other terms are random.

**Expected Result:**

```
class name extends #(p val1 = 10,
                     p val2 = 20,
                     p val3 = 30) f_name;

string t;
```

Trial done as below,

**Trial_command:**

```
sed -i '/^class/a\\string t;'
```

**Trial_Result:**

```
class name extends #(p val1 = 10,
string t;
                     p val2 = 20,
                     p val3 = 30) f_name;
```

The above command works proper if the class statement ends in the same line as below

```
class name extends f_name;
```

**But not working when its consumes multiple lines.**

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

Multiline techniques must be used. With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^\s*class\s+\w+\s+extends\b/{ :a; /;\s*$/!{N; ba}; s/$/\nstring t;/ }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lpe '$class=1 if /^class/; if ($class and /;$/) { $_ .= "\nstring t;"; $class = 0 }` file
```

The above command remembers when a line starting with `class` is seen. Then adds a line `string t;` and forgets that `class` is seen, when it sees a line ending with `;`.

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html for help on various options used.

Comment: Thanks for the response.   perl -lpe '$class=1 if /^class/; if ($class and /;$/) { $_ .= "\nstring t;"; $class = 0 }' file   --------> This works. But unable to get the change updated in the file. used -i, still dint work. Gives error as "cant open perl script :: No such file or directory found"

Comment: perl -i -lpe'$class=1 if /^class/; if ($class and /;$/) { $_ .= "\nstring t;"; $class = 0 }' file. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ed can do this.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat >> append.ed << EOF
\$
a

string t;
.
wq
EOF

ed -s filename < append.ed
rm -v ./append.ed
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. The OP is trying to print a string after a different multi-line string appears in the input file, not just trying to add a string to the end of a file - you could do that with `printf '\nstring t\n' >> filename`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed for `-z` (to read the whole input as a single string) and for `\n` to mean newline in the replacement text:

```
$ sed -z 's/class name extends[^;]*;/&\n\nstring t;/' file
class name extends #(p val1 = 10,
                     p val2 = 20,
                     p val3 = 30) f_name;

string t;
```

otherwise using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '
    { r = (NR>1 ? r ORS : "") $0 }
    END { sub(/class name extends[^;]*;/,"&\n\nstring t;",r); print r }
' file
class name extends #(p val1 = 10,
                     p val2 = 20,
                     p val3 = 30) f_name;

string t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This perl one-liner does the job:

```perl
perl -0777 -ape 's/\bclass \w+ extends[\s\S]+?;\K/\nstring t;/' file
class name extends #(p val1 = 10,
                     p val2 = 20,
                     p val3 = 30) f_name;
string t;
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/                # substitute
    \b              # word boundary
    class           # literally
    \w+             # 1 or more word characters (class name)
    extends         # literally
    [\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character including newline
    ;               # semi colon
    \K              # forget all we have seen until this position
/                 # with
    \n              # linefeed
    string t;       # literally
/                 # end subs
```

Comment: how to use this perl one-liner's when using inside perl script? I am getting error.          
 system ( "perl -i -lpe '$class=1 if /^class/; if ($class and /;$/) { $_ .= "\n string t\;"; $class = 0 }' $file_path");

Comment: system( q( perl -0777 -ape 's/\bclass \w+ extends[\s\S]+?;\K/\nstring t;/' file ) );  this is not working and giving error, when used inside perl script

Comment: @Hancy: Don't use `system(.....)`. Insid your Perl script, open the file (slurp mode) then execute the substitution and write the modified data.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^class/!b;:a;/;$/!{N;ba};/extends/astring t;' file
```

If the current line does not begin `class`, not interested.

If the current line does not end `;`, append the next line and repeat.

If the current line(s) contains `extended`, append another line `string  t;`.

---

If a blank line then a line containing `string t;` is required, either:

```
sed '/^class/!b;:a;/;$/!{N;ba};/extends/G;//astring t;' file
```

or:

```
sed '/^class/!b;:a;/;$/!{N;ba};/extends/a\\nstring t;' file
```